# Solving Trig Values

Tags: trigonometry

So given the size of the hypotenuse being $2$, the angle is $24°$, slope $\frac{3}{7}$.

I am looking for the opposite and the adjacent numbers.

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify which hypotenuse is 2-Is it the big hypotenuse or the small one? Same for adjacent too.

Comment: I voted to close (*unclear...*) because there are two angles listed, and neither of them is the inverse tangent of 3/7!

Comment: OP, what you need to (re)learn is "SOH CAH TOA". The sine of an angle is the ratio of its opposite to (over) hypotenuse. Etc.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 that was a typo. I was able to remember SOHCAHTOA (unforgivable), but all I had was the slope of the angle and the hypotenuse was 2. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Opp = $\color{blue}{h\sin(\phi)}$

Adj = $\color{blue}{h\cos(\phi)}$

Answer (score 1):

Note that m (slope) = $tan(\theta) = \frac{3}{7}$

Compare with: $tan(\theta) = \frac{opp}{adj}$

Comment: Which doesn't give an angle of $28$ degrees...

Comment: (or $24$ degrees, which is also in the question!)

Comment: That is true, very misleading. Good catch!

Comment: @JoshMelia to get that number I converted the slope in radians to degrees, is the slope useful at all?

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 `(3/7) * (180/PI) = 24.~`...

Comment: On the contrary, the **angle** isn't useful at all!

Comment: @EvanCarslake, you are making a critical error with that line of reasoning! There seems to be a fundamental error with your understanding of what a *radian* is.